# Passing multidimensionals vector to C++11 threads

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I'm working on a program that reads a large binary file (> 80GB) full of unsigned chars into a std::vector, then runs computations on chunks of the elements in that vector. I would like to speed things up by having independent threads run these computations on different sections of the vector simultaneously, and combine the results at the end.

These threads should all be storing the results of their calculations in a pair of 2-dimensional std::vectors, which I am attempting to pass into the thread function call as references. I can get this all to work in a generic function call, but when I try to launch it using std::thread I get the following compilation errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:39:0,
                 from test.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<int (*(long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned char>, std::vector<std::vector<long double> >, std::vector<std::vector<long long unsigned int> >))(long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned char>&, std::vector<std::vector<long double> >&, std::vector<std::vector<long long unsigned int> >&)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:137:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = int (&)(long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned char>&, std::vector<std::vector<long double> >&, std::vector<std::vector<long long unsigned int> >&); _Args = {long long unsigned int&, long long unsigned int&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::vector<std::vector<long double, std::allocator<long double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<long double, std::allocator<long double> > > >&, std::vector<std::vector<long long unsigned int, std::allocator<long long unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<long long unsigned int, std::allocator<long long unsigned int> > > >&}]’
test.cpp:44:130:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<int (*(long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned char>, std::vector<std::vector<long double> >, std::vector<std::vector<long long unsigned int> >))(long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned char>&, std::vector<std::vector<long double> >&, std::vector<std::vector<long long unsigned int> >&)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<int (*(long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned char>, std::vector<std::vector<long double> >, std::vector<std::vector<long long unsigned int> >))(long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned char>&, std::vector<std::vector<long double> >&, std::vector<std::vector<long long unsigned int> >&)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
     ^
```

I'm compiling in Linux using g++ 4.8.2 using:

```
g++ -Wall test.cpp -o test -std=c++0x
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much!

My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>


int functionToRun (unsigned long long startingNum, unsigned long long endingNum, std::vector<unsigned char>& mainReadCountVector, std::vector<std::vector<long double>>& threadPWP, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long long int>>& threadWeightings);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int numThreads = 32;

    std::streampos size;
    std::ifstream file ("data.bin", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        // Create and populate the vector that holds all the data in the binary file
        size = file.tellg();
        file.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);
        std::vector<unsigned char> data(size);
        file.read((char*) &data[0], size);
        file.close();

        // The resulting calculations within each thread will be stored in a 2D vector that looks like std::vector<std::vector<long double>> calc1(272, std::vector<long double>(272,0)) and std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long long int>> calc2(272, std::vector<unsigned long long int>(272,0))
        // Create one of these vectors for each of the threads by making a 3D vector:
        std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long double>>> calc1(numThreads, std::vector<std::vector<long double>> (272, std::vector<long double> (272,0) ) ); //calc1[0] is the first 2D array for the first thread, etc...
        std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long long int>>> calc2(numThreads, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long long int> > (272, std::vector<unsigned long long int> (272,0) ) );

        //Launch a group of threads
        std::vector<std::thread> threadsVec;
        for (int threadRunning = 0; threadRunning < numThreads; threadRunning++) {
            unsigned long long firstNum = threadRunning * 1000000;
            unsigned long long secondNum = (threadRunning * 1000000) + 1000000 - 1;
            threadsVec.push_back(std::thread(functionToRun, firstNum, secondNum, data, calc1[threadRunning], calc2[threadRunning]));
        }

        // Wait on threads to finish
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
            threadsVec[i].join();
        }

        // Now aggregate the results of the threads
        std::vector<std::vector<long double>> calc1Sum(272, std::vector<long double>(272,0));
        std::vector<std::vector<long double>> calc2Sum(272, std::vector<long double>(272,0));
        for (int element = 0; element < 272; element++) {
            for (int comparisonElement = 0; comparisonElement <= element; comparisonElement++) {
                for (int threadVector = 0; threadVector <= numThreads; threadVector++) {
                    calc1Sum[element][comparisonElement] += calc1[threadVector][element][comparisonElement];
                    calc2Sum[element][comparisonElement] += calc2[threadVector][element][comparisonElement];
                }
            }
        }
    } else std::cout << "Unable to open data.bin";

    return 0;
}


int functionToRun (unsigned long long startingNum, unsigned long long endingNum, std::vector<unsigned char>& mainDataVector, std::vector<std::vector<long double>>& calc1ret, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long long int>>& calc2ret) {

    int internalData[272];

    for (unsigned long long dataSpot = startingNum; dataSpot < endingNum; dataSpot++) {
        for (int ind1 = 0; ind1 < 272; ind1++) {
            unsigned long long firstIndex = dataSpot * 544 + 2 * ind1;
            unsigned long long secondIndex = dataSpot * 544 + 2 * ind1 + 1;
            internalData[ind1] = mainDataVector[firstIndex] + mainDataVector[secondIndex];

            for (int ind2 = 0; ind2 <= ind1; ind2++) {
                calc1ret[ind1][ind2] = internalData[ind1] + internalData[ind2];
                calc2ret[ind1][ind2] = internalData[ind1] / (std::pow(internalData[ind2],2));
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using `std::ref` to wrap those vectors in a `reference_wrapper`. The `INVOKE` machinery used by `std::thread` is attempting to copy them: `threadsVec.emplace_back(functionToRun, firstNum, secondNum, std::ref(data), std::ref(calc1[threadRunning]), std::ref(calc2[threadRunning]));`

Comment: If only chunks of the file are being analyzed at a time, do you really need to load the entire 80GB into memory like that? Why not read in the first chunk from ifstream, then dispatch a thread to handle it, then read another chunk, etc? Your main process could be more like a scheduler, instead of giving the full file to every thread when they may not need all of it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If I wrap all three vectors (data, calc1[threadRunning], and calc2[threadRunning]) in std::ref, then it does indeed compile.

Comment: Regarding accessing the file, I would recommend using a memory map (either `mmap()` directly, or use something like Boost to wrap it); just let the OS fetch the data from the disk as the threads try to read them.